# Multiple calls with retrofit2 and rxjava3

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I want to make multiple calls at the same time using retrofit. When both calls end, I want to make something with the results.

Here is my interface

```
public interface IService {
    @GET("all")
    Observable<Global> getGlobal();

    @GET("countries")
    Observable<Country> getCountries();
}
```

This is my incomplete code

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();

        IService api = retrofit.create(IService.class);

        List<Observable<?>> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        requests.add(api.getGlobal());
        requests.add(api.getCountries());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) operator

```
val service:IService

Observable.zip(
    service.global,
    service.countries,
    BiFunction { global, countries -> 
        // combine result
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Observable.combineLatest()` is what you need, so it will looks like:

```
Observable<YourResult> observable = Observable
    .combineLatest( 
        api.getGlobal(), 
        api.getCountries(), 
        { global, country -> YourResult(global, country) }
    )
```